# The set of fixed-rank maps is open

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $ V $ and $ W $ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $ \mathbb R $. Let $ n = \dim V $ and $ m = \dim W $, and suppose $ n\leqq m $.

Given any $ r = 1,\dots,n $, I want to show that the set of rank $ r $ linear maps from $ V $ to $ W $ is open in the set $ \hom(V,W) $.

I picked some $ T\in \hom(V,W) $ such that $ \operatorname{rk} T = r $ and I decomposed $ V $ and $ W $ as
$$
V = V_1\oplus V_2\qquad W= W_1\oplus W_2
$$
where $ V_2 = \ker T $ and $ W_1 = \operatorname{im} T $. Then I observed that
$$
\hom(V,W)\cong \bigoplus_{i,j}\hom(V_i,W_j)
$$
by
$$
T\leftrightarrow (T_{ij})_{i,j}
$$
where $ T_{ij}\colon V_i\to W_j $ is the restriction of the composition
$$
V\xrightarrow{\pi_i} V\xrightarrow{T} W\xrightarrow{\sigma_j} W
$$
where the $ \sigma $s and the $ \pi $s are the obvious projection operators. Observe that $ T_{11} $ is invertible (indeed, it's the identity  map), and $ T_{ij} = 0 $ for both $ i\neq 1 $ and $ j\neq 1 $.

I then used the isomorphism
$$
\hom(V_1,W_1)\cong \mathrm{Matrices}_{r\times r}(\mathbb R)
$$
and the continuity of the determinant function
$$
\mathrm{Matrices}_{r\times r}(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R
$$
to determine an open set $ U_{11}\subset \hom(V_1,W_1) $, and ultimately an open set
$$
U_{11}\times \hom(V_1,W_2)\times \dots\subset \bigoplus_{i,j}\hom(V_1,W_j)\text{.}
$$

This should complete the proof. I mean, every $ S_{11}\in U_{11} $ gives a rank $ r $ linear map $ (S_{11},T_{12},T_{21},T_{22}) $, right? $ \square $

I have my reasons to believe this proof is flawed. Am I wrong, and indeed my argument holds?

Comment: This is only true for $r = \min(n, m) = n$

Comment: It seems to me that you are proving that the set is open "in some directions", since you are fixing $V_1$ and $W_1$. What happens if you perturb your map in a way that changes $V_1$, say your map is a projection on a subspace and you perturb a bit the subspace?

Answer (score 1):

Matrices in $U_{11} \times \hom(V_1, W_2) \times 0 \times 0$ have rank $r$ but other matrices in $U_{11} \times \dotsb$ will have higher rank (since their kernel is strictly contained in $V_2$ and therefore have lower nullity).

You do get an open subset of $\hom(V_1, W)$ but as you take the union over various $V_1$ this will not be open in $\hom(V, W)$ (unless $V_1 = V$, ie $r = n$).